# Animate CALayer - zoom and scroll

Tags: xcode, core-animation, zooming, calayer

I want to create an animation with CALayers.
I have a parent layer with multiple sublayers and I would like to zoom in and scroll.

First I trying to zoom on the parent layer, as follows:

```
let transformAnimation = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "bounds.size.width")
transformAnimation.duration = 2.3
transformAnimation.timingFunction = CAMediaTimingFunction(name: kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseInEaseOut)
transformAnimation.toValue =  650*2 
transformAnimation.beginTime = CACurrentMediaTime() + 4
transformAnimation.autoreverses = false
transformAnimation.isRemovedOnCompletion = false
transformAnimation.fillMode = kCAFillModeForwards
parentLayer.add(transformAnimation, forKey: "transformAnimation")
//
let transformAnimation2 = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "bounds.size.height")
transformAnimation2.duration = 2.3
transformAnimation2.timingFunction = CAMediaTimingFunction(name: kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseInEaseOut)
transformAnimation2.toValue =  650*2 //CGAffineTransform.identity
transformAnimation2.beginTime = CACurrentMediaTime() + 4
transformAnimation2.autoreverses = false
transformAnimation2.isRemovedOnCompletion = false
transformAnimation2.fillMode = kCAFillModeForwards
parentLayer.add(transformAnimation2, forKey: "transformAnimation2")
```

When the animation is applied, the sublayers are left in wrong position and size. Should I also apply the animation to them?
How can I do this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm guessing that you're updating `width` and `height` of one layer and you're wondering whether the `bounds` of sublayers will also change. No, you'll probably have to animate those separately, too. But rather than initiating separate animations, you can them with a `CAAnimationGroup`.

If these were views, you could define constraints that coordinate the resizing of subviews more gracefully. But with layers, you're going to have to do this yourself. (There might be reasons why you're doing it the way you are, but it's not clear from the question.)

Comment: Thanks Rob! I will try that